# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'lastname') - Form - Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm having an issue in my form. Every time I press a key to add a character in the input (I took the lastname example but I get the same error for each of them) I get this error.

[image: Vue warn]

[image: Uncaught TypeError]

Form is working but anyway I would like to clean these errors. I've been trying my myself but I don't see what is wrong.

Here is the part of my code the error is refering to:

```
    const resetError = (field) => {
  validationErrors.value.contactForm[field] = null;
};
```

```js
const contactData = reactive({
  lastname: null,
  firstname: null,
  email: null,
  textarea: null,
});

const resetError = (field) => {
  validationErrors.value.contactForm[field] = null;
};

const active = ref(false);
const loading = ref(false);

const submitContact = async (event) => {
  try {
    validationErrors.value["contactForm"] = {};

    const isValid = await validateData(
      "contactForm",
      contactSchema,
      contactData
    );

    if (!isValid) return;

    loading.value = true;
    await airtableStore.fetchAirtablePortfolio(contactData);
    loading.value = false;
    toggleModal(true);
    event.target.reset();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

```html
<form @submit.prevent="submitContact">
  <form-input-molecule
    label="Nom:"
    id="lastname"
    name="lastname"
    v-model="contactData.lastname"
    placeholder="Doe"
    @input="resetError('lastname')"
    :error-message="validationErrors.contactForm?.lastname"
  ></form-input-molecule>
  <button-atom type="submit" :disabled="loading" :active="active"
  >Envoyer</button-atom>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found where the problem was coming from.

Here are my changes:

```
const contactData = ref({
  lastname: null,
  firstname: null,
  email: null,
  textarea: null,
});

const resetError = (field) => {
  if (validationErrors.value.contactForm?.[field]) {
    validationErrors.value.contactForm[field] = null;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue might be related to default values of contactData. I would set those to strings.

```js
const contactData = reactive({
  lastname: '',
  firstname: '',
  email: '',
  textarea: '',
});
```

Otherwise, I don't see it from your snippets, but if you're using setup() you need to return contactData for it to be available in the template.